# How to know given query belogings to which tables in sphinx/php?

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I have 2 tables in my DB such as `State` and `Interest`.

I am building an app where I need to implement generic search like google.
Means, user can enter combinations like below:

1. `Music` in `California` [`Music` belongs to `Interest` and `California`
   belongs to `State`]
2. `Florida`
3. `Music` etc.

Now, I want to get best results by applying indexing on both tables `State` and `Interest`.
But, before that I need to categorize the query words to identify where should I apply it to get best results.

**`State` table** contains states in USA like `Florida`, `Albama`, `California` etc.

and

**`Interest` table** contains interests like `Music`, `Concerts` etc.

I am new to `PHP` and `sphinx`. I need suggestions and no coding answers required for now.

Answer (score 0):

How do the two tables 'join' ? - ie how know there results for Music in California.

At the moment, just mentioning two seperate tables.

Seems you have some other 'table' of actual documents? The items want to actully find. ie you want to find documents about Music in California

... so its THIS table you actully index. Interest and State are just two fields on this index.

Then could search

```
$query = "keywords @state Claifornia @interest Music";
```

But actully just searching without fieldnames would work too

```
$query = "keywords Claifornia Music";
```

but if California happens in some other fields (like a description) will match too.

Comment: Your answer sounds confusing. As I have mentioned that State and Interest are 2 different tables with few other columns as well in each

Comment: ok, so HOW do they 'join'? There must be some link between the two tables. Interest and state belong in seperate fields, not seperate indexes.